# SQLite row disappears after executing select query

Tags: java, sqlite, row, delete-row

I am using SQLite database with java servlets for my cinema application.

I have DAO which communicates with db. After making select query to database, random row gets deleted.

Here is the method that gives me list of projections based on movie, but it somehow deletes row in the table everytime it gets called. (It always deletes row on top and after that random rows).

```
public static List<Projection> getAllByMovie(Integer movie_id) {

        List<Projection> projections = new ArrayList<>();

        Connection con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM projections WHERE movie = ? AND dateandtime >= '2020-02-11'";

            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setInt(1, movie_id);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int index = 1;
                int id = rs.getInt(index++);
                int title = rs.getInt(index++);
                int projection_type = rs.getInt(index++);
                int theater_rs = rs.getInt(index++);
                String date_and_time = rs.getString(index++);
                double price = rs.getDouble(index++);
                int admin_creator = rs.getInt(index++);

                Theater theater = TheaterDAO.get(theater_rs);
                Movie movie = MovieDAO.get(title);
                ProjectionType projectionType = ProjectionTypeDAO.get(projection_type);
                Projection projection = new Projection();
                projection.setId(id);
                projection.setMovie(movie.getTitle());
                projection.setProjectionType(projectionType.getName());
                projection.setTheater(theater.getName());
                Date date = sdf.parse(date_and_time);
                projection.setDateOutput(date_and_time);
                projection.setDateAndTime(date);
                projection.setTicketPrice(price);
                projection.setAdminCreator(admin_creator);

                projections.add(projection);

            }

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {ps.close();} catch (Exception ex1) {ex1.printStackTrace();}
            try {rs.close();} catch (Exception ex1) {ex1.printStackTrace();}
        }

        return projections;
    }
```

I always get desired result with this query, but it randomly removes row.

I have many other methods and queries for database, but none invokes this kind of behaviour.

EDIT: I came to conclusion, initially there are 25 projections (rows) in table, it deletes rows until there's 15 left! (first 10 rows get deleted, first row then other 9 in random order)

What the hell is going on?

Comment: I have a hunch in mind. Can you please show the calling method from where getAllByMovie() DAO gets called?

Comment: I think I figured it out, I was having switch with cases and getAllByMovie case was missing break at the end, so it probably went to next method which is delete...